nicegui deployment on cpanel, .htaccess
I am trying to deploy nicegui app on cpanel. python app on cpanel require wsgi callable object. I need help to deploy either by using wsgi or editing .htaccess
Instead of wsgi callable I am trying to run directly using below method-
source /home/username/virtualenv/tools/3.9/bin/activate && cd /home/username/tools
python main.py

nicegui runs on port 8080. I have modified .htaccess so as to redirect http and websocket request on port 80 to port 8080 on localhost.
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION BEGIN
<IfModule Litespeed>
</IfModule>
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION END

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Proxy requests to nicegui server
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ws://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L]
</IfModule>


using this page loads on port 80 but only partially. only loads frame but contents are not rendered.
on terminal I see only below error-
The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)

Help wanted to either method, wsgi or .htaccess. Thanks
